# How to connect RJ45 (female) Link LED

Tags: led, raspberry-pi, diy, rj45

I need a bit of help. I have some Jtron RJ45 sockets (do a quick search, for a better picture), and they have LEDs integrated.
I want to connect these sockets to a PCB and get the internet in (added passive POE 24V), but I have no idea how to make the LEDs work (flickering if internet is connected and transferring data)!

Do I just connect them to RX and TX? 
Is there any standard to do this?

Here is a very primitive scheme on how I plan to use this RJ45+LM2596 module:

[image]

The LEDs on the image are actually the LEDs integrated in RJ45.

Comment: Ethernet doesn't work that way. You can't just hook LEDs to the TX and RX lines. The device on the end of the cable which is actually communicating over Ethernet must have a PHY IC and ths is the thing which will control those status LEDs.

Comment: Aha, I was assuming something is not ok.
So I cannot just put a PHY IC chip between my two RJ45 to make LED work?
Can you propose a chip?

Comment: No, you can't just put a single PHY there. You need one for each link and something to move data between them. By the time you have the electronics needed you would have built an ethernet hub. Google Ethernet PHY IC if you want a list of chips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a standard. It is to connect them to the LED pins on the Ethernet PHY device used. That can drive them based on the programmed criteria (normally activity and link status/speed)

If you're not connecting to the Ethernet network and only passing the connections through then there is no easy way to trigger those LEDs based on network activity.

Comment: Yes I am using it to pass Ethernet Data (1,2,3,6) + Power(4,5,7,8), 5V output and split power from the cable(because RaspberryPi3 is not sporting POE).
What do you mean by Ethernet PHY? How do I connect the LED in my case?

Comment: The PHY is the physical layer interface chip, the part that decodes the Ethernet data. How do you do it in your case? You don't. You could use one LED for power in. For the second LED you could measure the current draw and indicate when a PoE device is connected. It won't tell you if there is data but it would indicate something using power.

Comment: You could use a output pin on your RPi to drive the data pin under software control whenever your application receives or sends data packets.  Using the other LED to indicate available PoE voltage as suggested by @Andrew is a good idea.

Comment: I think it`s pretty clear to me now, thank you all!